# What is the correct order in Configuring ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, configuration, asp.net-core, static-files

I've got an ASP.NET Core application with several Web Api controllers. I can't tell if there is some connection, but the application was created with VS2015 update 2, and now I'm working with VS2015 update 3. 
So I created another Web Api controller, and when there is a query to that controller I'm having this exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider.GetFullPath(String path)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider.GetFileInfo(String subpath)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles.StaticFileContext.LookupFileInfo()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

The funny thing is that somehow StaticFileMiddleware is involved in processing a simple request to controller. While I can fix the problem by changing the order of configuring the application by calling

```
app.UseMvc(...
```

before

```
app.UseStaticFiles()
```

I still want to know how this happened and what's the correct order of configuring the application.

Keep in mind that all previously added controllers are working just fine with both ways of configuring, but the new one can work only with the latter.

The new controller do not operate with static files.

**EDITED**
Routing:
In controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ViewsController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("{path}", Name = "Views")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string path)
        {
            return Json("bla");
        }
    }
```

In Startup.cs:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "angular2app",
                template: "ng/{*.}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "api",
                template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

The troubled request:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/Views/blablapath
```

Comment: Please post some code from the controller that causes "trouble".

Comment: That's the thing. The code from the controller do not cause any trouble, because the call never reaches the controller. The exception occures before.

Comment: My reason to ask for the controller code is that there probably is something that makes it "special" compared to the previous existing controllers; like Route-Annotations, special naming or whatever...

Comment: Can you show the configured route for the Web API controller which is not working? And also the path you are requesting which causes this exception.

Comment: Well, there is nothing really special. I also put code from the other controller inside this one, hoping that the trick will show something, but the very same error occured as before. And the routing in the controller is standart for the webapi controller.

Comment: Okay, here's the routing. Controller: [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ViewsController : Controller , Action: [HttpGet("{path}", Name = "Views")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string path).
The troubled path: http://localhost:5000/api/Views/E%3A%5Cworkspace%5CHtmlMapperTest%5CCourse.xml

Comment: The static file middle ware is involved because you probably have a `Views` Folder in your project which is causing a conflict. The middle ware sees the physical `Views` folder matched by your request to `/api/Views/blablapath` and craps out as it can't handle the extension-less path format. 

Check to see if you have a folder conflict or rename the `ViewsController` to something else and It should work.

Comment: I see that your requests ends with .xml

Comment: @DmitryVolkov: The the API routing isn't standard. On Api controllers typically there aren't any actions. WebAPI  uses Http Verbs instead. The default route for WebAPI is `api/{controller}/{id?}` or just use attribute based routing `[Route("api/[controller]")]` on your controller and `HttpGet("{id}")]` on your action methods

Comment: @DemitryVolkov: I created an empty ASP.NET Core Project with no authentication and made modifications to the startup.cs (routing) and added the Views Controller. Unfortunately the URL /api/Views/blablapath returns (as expected) the JSON string "bla". There has to be another difference...

Comment: @tmg You were right, thank you, if request seems to contain a path to some file, static files middleware interceptes it.
Write it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Core2 preview mixed with release nugets, **you have to add the static file nuget** to your project. (Core2 already include it but you still have to add it to solve some issues)

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles